# Where does "data-toggle" attribute of bootstrap framework come from?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use some of the jQuery plugins for the [Bootstrap framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) and they use an attribute named "data-toggle".  I am getting the warning "attribute data toggle is not a valid atribute of a".

Where does data-toggle come form?

Comment: [Follow this link for bootstrap documentation regarding "data-toggle" and so on.](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#overview) Hope this helps although it is coming at a late hour

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In HTML5, any attribute that starts with `data-` is a valid **custom** attribute. Basically, it's a way to attach custom data to elements that aren't explicitly defined in the HTML specification.

In earlier versions of HTML, this does not validate, however. Don't worry about that too much though. Browsers generally just ignore attributes they don't know about. This doesn't stop libraries like `jQuery` from reading them.

Answer (score 21):

If you look in the [JavaScript Collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) documentation of Bootstrap you will find a reasonably clear example of the workings of the collapse API and the relationship and uses of the pair `data-toggle` (which triggers the functionality) and `data-target` (which sets the behavior), plus other interesting tidbits.

Answer (score 19):

It is a Bootstrap defined HTML5 data attribute.

Comment: Oh ok, so why isn't it "valid"? where is it defined?

Comment: what is your doctype? who is giving you the warning?

Comment: try including the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) library for versions of IE less than 9, assuming you have the HTML5 doctypes set.

Answer (score 4):

To quickly add `dropdown` functionality to any element just add `data-toggle="dropdown"` defined `HTML5` data attribute, and any valid bootstrap `dropdown` will automatically be activated.