# The data-toggle attributes in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What does `data-toggle` attributes do in Twitter Bootstrap? I couldn't find an answer in Bootstrap API.

I have seen a similar question before as well, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481684/where-does-data-toggle-attribute-of-bootstrap-framework-come-from).
But it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

It is a Bootstrap data attribute that automatically hooks up the element to the type of widget it is. Data-* is part of the html5 spec, and data-toggle is specific to Bootstrap.

Some Examples:

```
data-toggle="modal"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-toggle="tab"
```

Go through the [Bootstrap JavaScript docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/javascript/) and search for data-toggle and you will see it used in the code examples.

One working example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is just an HTML attribute which is used with selectors, not HTML5 specific.

Comment: @UmurKontacı data-* was introduced in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like the link of JavaScript docs is changed  to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html. Please verify it.

Comment: I guess 'JavaScript docs' link has broken.  Anyone can provide updated one?

Comment: You have made it sound like data-toggle is part of html5 spec instead of data-* is html5 and data-toggle is Bootstrap.

Comment: You forgot a </li> closing tag on line 4. :)

Comment: And 'data-toggle' isn't even bootstrap-specific, just that bootstrap chose to use data-* attribute with the name 'toggle'. So you might encounter a 'data-toggle' attribute not related to bootstrap in another project.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I use `data-toggle="buttons"` to fake radios as buttons, it messes up my event listeners on the radios.

Answer (score 75):

Any attribute that starts with `data-` is the prefix for custom attributes used for some specific purpose (that purpose depends on the application). It was added as a semantic remedy to people's heavy use of `rel` and other attributes for purposes other than their original intended purposes (`rel` was often used to hold data for things like advanced tooltips).

In the case of Bootstrap, I'm not familiar with its inner workings, but judging from the name, I'd guess it's a hook to allow toggling of the visibility or perhaps a mode of the element it's attached to (such as the collapsable side bar [on Octopress.org](http://octopress.org/)).

[html5doctor has a good article on the data- attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

[Cycle 2 is another example of extensive use of the data- attribute](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

Comment: "In HTML5, any attribute that starts with data- is a valid custom attribute. Basically, it's a way to attach custom data to elements that aren't explicitly defined in the HTML specification."

Answer (score 30):

For example, say you were creating a web application to list and display recipes. You might want your customers to be able to sort the list, display features of the recipes, and so on before they choose the recipe to open. In order to do this, you need to associate things like cooking time, primary ingredient, meal position, and so on right inside the list elements for the recipes.

```
<li><a href="recipe1.html">Borscht</a></li>
<li><a href="recipe2.html">Chocolate Mousse</a></li>
<li><a href="recipe3.html">Almond Radiccio Salad</a></li>
<li><a href="recipe4.html">Deviled Eggs</a></li>
```

In order to get that information into the page, you could do many different things. You could add comments to each LI element, you could add rel attributes to the list items, you could place all the recipes in separate folders based on time, meal, and ingredient (i.e. ). The solution that most developers took was to use class attributes to store information about the current element. This has several advantages:

- You can store multiple classes on an element
- The class names can be human readable
- It’s easy to access classes with JavaScript (className)
- The class is associated with the element it’s on

But there are some major drawbacks to this method:

- You have to remember what the classes do. If you forget or a new developer takes over the project, the classes might be removed or changed without realizing that that affects how the application runs.
- Classes are also used for styling with CSS, and you might duplicate CSS classes with data classes by mistake, ending up with strange styles on your live pages.
- It’s more difficult to add on multiple data elements. If you have multiple data elements, you need to access them in some way with your JavaScript, either by the name of the class or the position in the class list. But it’s easy to mess up.

All the other methods I suggested had these problems as well as others. But since it was the only way to quickly and easily include data, that’s what we did.
HTML5 Data Attributes to the Rescue

HTML5 added a new type of attribute to any element—the custom data element (data-*). These are custom (denoted by the *) attributes that you can add to your HTML elements to define any type of data you want. They consist of two parts:

Attribute Name
This is the name of the attribute. It must be at least one lowercase character and have the prefix data-. For example: data-main-ingredient, data-cooking-time, data-meal. This is the name of your data.

Attribute Vaule
Like any other HTML attribute, you include the data itself in quotes separated by an equal sign. This data can be any string that is valid on a web page. For example: data-main-ingredient="chocolate".

You can then apply these data attributes to any HTML element you want. For example, you could define the information in the example list above:

```
<li data-main-ingredient="beets" data-cooking-time="1 hour" data-meal="dinner"><a href="recipe1.html">Borscht</a></li>
<li data-main-ingredient="chocolate" data-cooking-time="30 minutes" data-meal="dessert"><a href="recipe2.html">Chocolate Mousse</a></li>
<li data-main-ingredient="radiccio" data-cooking-time="20 minutes" data-meal="dinner"><a href="recipe1.html">Almond Radiccio Salad</a></li>
<li data-main-ingredient="eggs" data-cooking-time="15 minutes" data-meal="appetizer"><a href="recipe1.html">Deviled Eggs</a></li>
```

Once you have that information in your HTML, you will be able to access it with JavaScript and manipulate the page based on that data.

Answer (score 27):

From the [Bootstrap Docs:](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

```
<!--Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="modal" on a 
controller element, like a button, along with a data-target="#foo" or href="#foo" 
to target a specific modal to toggle.-->

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

Answer (score 11):

So many answers have been given, but they don't get to the point. Let's fix this.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

**To the point**

1. Any attribute starting with `data-` is not parsed by the HTML5 parser.
2. Bootstrap uses the `data-toggle` attribute to create collapse functionality.

**How to use**:  Only 2 Steps

1. Add `class="collapse"` to the element `#A` you want to collapse.
2. Add `data-target="#A"` and `data-toggle="collapse"`.

Purpose: the `data-toggle` attribute allows us to create a control to collapse/expand a `div` (block) if we use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

The presence of this data-attribute tells Bootstrap to switch between visual or a logical states of another element on user interaction.

It is used to show modals, tab content, tooltips and popover menus as well as setting a pressed-state for a toggle-button. It is used in multiple ways without a clear documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of data-toggle in bootstrap is so you can use jQuery to find all tags of a certain type.  For example, you put data-toggle="popover" in all popover tags and then you can use a JQuery selector to find all those tags and run the popover() function to initialize them.  You could just as well put class="myPopover" on the tag and use the .myPopover selector to do the same thing.  The documentation is confusing, because it makes it appear that something special is going on with that attribute.

This

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" class="myPop" title="Popover1 Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover1">Toggle popover1</a>
    <a href="#" class="myPop" title="Popover2 Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover2">Toggle popover2</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myPop').popover();   
    });
</script>
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

It is a Bootstrap defined HTML5 data attribute. It binds a button to an event.

Comment: It's not limited to buttons and/or events.

Comment: I don't see the button's event listener in chrome devtools

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) you can also find more examples for values that `data-toggle` can have assigned. Just visit the page and then `CTRL+F` to search for `data-toggle`.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap leverages HTML5 standards in order to access DOM element attributes easily within javascript.

### data-*

> Forms a class of attributes, called custom data attributes, that allow proprietary information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation that may be used by scripts. All such custom data are available via the HTMLElement interface of the element the attribute is set on. The HTMLElement.dataset property gives access to them.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*)