# Submitting form using controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm trying to call a method from view, but it's not working! :(

My Controller code:

```
public class ProfessionalController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Professional/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Sum(int nro1, int nro2)
    {
        var value = nro1 + nro2;

        ViewBag.SumResult = value;

        return View();
    }
}
```

My views code:

**Professional Index:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profissional";
}

<h2>Profissional</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Professional", "Sum")) {

    <input id="nro1" type="number" class="form-control marged_top" placeholder="Numero 1" />
    <input id="nro2" type="number" class="form-control marged_top" placeholder="Numero 2" />


    <button id="Sum" name="Sum" value="Sum" class="btn btn-default" type="button"
            data-toggle="button">

        Sum
    </button>

}
```

**Sum View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sum";
}

<h2>Sum</h2>


@ViewBag.SumResult;
```

Doesn't occurs any error, just nothing happens when i click at Sum button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You probably want your `<button>` with `type="submit"`, otherwise the form will not be submitted, and the button will do nothing. See also: [MDN - Button Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)
- `Html.BeginForm("Professional", "Sum")` should be `Html.BeginForm("Sum", "Professional")` - The controller is the second argument.
  `Html.BeginForm("Sum")` would also work here, because this is the current controller.
- The inputs should have `name="nro1"`, not `id` - it is the name that is being submitted.
- No need for semicolon after `@ViewBag.SumResult` (though that isn't a bug).
- I'm not sure what [`data-toggle="button"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113537/7586) is doing here.

Note that you are not "calling a Controller from a View" - you are submitting a form, which starts a new Controller-View cycle. [`Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423.aspx) can do something similar, but that is not what you're trying to do here.

<sub>I'd also take this opportunity and recommend against using `ViewBag` - [Use a strongly typed view model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7993263/7586) instead</sub>

Comment: I've changed the type to `submit`, but it still doesn't works :(