# Angular JS ng-repeat and modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, dialog

I am iterating over a list of students and each row has the student name and college and a button. On clicking the button you see a modal dialog which shows student details. For some reason I am unable to get the correct student information. The dialog just shows the 1'st student information only. Here is the pluker

http://plnkr.co/edit/kXB7OZuyOz57qyVMIu8T?p=preview

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat = "student in students">
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{student.college}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogTestDialog">Options</button>
                    </div>
                    <div   class="modal fade" id="dialogTestDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="executionOptionLabel"
                            aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                    Student : {{student.name}} <br/> Detail on Student
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>{{student.age}}</p>
                                        <p>{{student.address}}</p>
                                        <p>{{student.race}}</p>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all your modals have the same id value, so this is not valid html. You need different id values so you can reference the correct one on click. eg: `ng-click="showModal($index)"`

I would check this out:

[How to set the id attribute of a HTML element dynamically with angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js)

Also if you really want to play with bootstrap js and angular, you should use a version specific to angular: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Check this version in Plunker: [Working Version](http://plnkr.co/edit/qFIBIcdNT7rU4TZ2r2nF)

To get the ng-repeat index value ,  you have to use `{{ $index }}` [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

and to data-toggle should be the values specified in bootstrap [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113537/what-does-data-toggle-do-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Thank you. You save my life