# Bootstrap data-toggle not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, safari

The below code making use of bootstrap's `data-toggle="collapse"` to do the functionality of collapse/expand on click of configured element,
In this case, clicking `parent1` and `parent2`

**Problem:** On click of `parent` element, the collapse is working from my PC using Chrome and firefox browsers, but it is not working from my iPad using safari browser.

```
<div id="parent1" type="button" class="parentclass" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childof1">
  <strong>Technologies </strong>
</div>

<div id="childof1" class="collapse">
  <!-- elements of child1 -->
</div

<div id="parent2" type="button" class="parentclass" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childof2">
  <strong>Vertical </strong>
</div>

<div id="childof2" class="collapse">
  <!-- elements of child2 -->
</div
```

References: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried using a `<a>` instead of `<div>` in parent elements where we click to expand/collapse, ie

```html
<a id="parent1" type="button" class="parentclass" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childof1">
  <strong>Technologies </strong>
</a>
```

and updated the styling of `parentclass` to have `display: block;`, and tested in iPad, now its working from iPad safari browser too!

**Updates 1:**
Saw one post where it is suggesting also to use `href` to make Safari in iPhone understand, but I am not sure if I must use that attribute too, as when I test with `href` too, everytime I touch on the `parent` header, the page gives an impression of refreshing [page moves]. So thinking that `href` is not needed.

```
<a id="parent1" type="button" class="parentclass" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#childof1" href="#childof1">
```

**Updates 2**

Updated using `<button>` instead of `<a>` so that expectation of an `href` could be easily ruled out. The output is still as expected, working in Chrome, Firefox as well as Safari.

**Please suggest** if this is correct approach or have any alternate fixes

more about `data-toggle` and `data-*`: [The data-toggle attributes in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113537/the-data-toggle-attributes-in-twitter-bootstrap?rq=1)

Comment: I had the same problem, and adding href="javascript: void(0)" fixed the problem for me. The old javascript void trick avoids any page refreshing problems.

Comment: @fred2, thanks for that point, I think that's good one, however I am still using `<button>` because if we are not making use of `href` attribute, then why to use the `<a>` tag, it's better to use `<button>`. That's how I'm thinking now

Comment: Sure - not suggesting it's a better solution, just an alternative one.

Comment: Adding `href="#"` to the `a` tag made it work on iPhone 6 Safari.

Comment: following up on fred2's suggestion above, if you're using a `<button...>` tag, within the tag, add `onclick="javascript:void(0)"`