# Toggle sidebar button is not visible in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm working on a website based on Bootstrap 4, with a collapsing sidebar.

The toggle button is visible in chrome and firefox on windows and macos just fine.
But it isn't visible in safari on macos.

I tried a lot of solutions like playing around with options e.g.:

`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);`
or `transform-style: preserve-3d;`

without any luck.

I don't want to put too much code in here so I've made a codepen where you can see the actual behaviour: https://codepen.io/pen/JqRLKx

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313761/bootstrap-data-toggle-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the solution mentioned there with no luck. In my example the collapse of the sidebar is working as expected in all browsers only the toggle button isn't visible in safari at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I might have narrowed down your issue. I could repro what you had on Safari.

After a lot of deleting and seeing what line causes the issue I found that overflow-y: auto is causing the issues.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
position: fixed;
left: 21rem;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -21rem;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #fafa;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

}

Now removing that line will display dropdown items. I am not sure how you can solve that problem. I ll update my answer if I find a solution
Give it a shot.

**EDIT**

try this [JQuery slide toggle menu](https://codepen.io/codeycodecode/pen/hxfws)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I can't figure out how i can adapt it to my needs. [link](https://codepen.io/pen/JqRLKx) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On my Safari I've moved it to the right of the forward/backward arrows.
I just added one flex space to the right of the sidebar icon, and the bug is gone.