# In a footable what is data-toggle doing?

Tags: jquery, html, footable

In a footable what is data-toggle doing?

```
<tr><th data-toggle="true">Attributes</th></tr>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113537/the-data-toggle-attributes-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: this is not the same